# A way to edit pbxproj without Xcode resolving package graph?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have tried to create a script that edits CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION accordingly in the .pbxproj file. But every time the script runs (when I archive), Xcode has to resolve package graph, which then cancels my archive.

Is it possible to edit without Xcode interfering?

I know I can just edit the Info.plist, but I might have multiple targets. Instead of looping through all these targets, I would rather just change CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION and then every Info.plist in every target points to CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION.

I have also tried using xcconfig files to do this. But that also does not work.